# Spectral analysis in R, how to interpret periodogram

Tags: r, time-series, fourier-transform

I'm relatively new to spectral analysis and have been working through some online tutorials. I have some time series data that I would like to examine for periodicity / repeating patterns.

When I create the periodogram there is a strong harmonic at 3Hz.
(though it looks weak in the excerpt of data I have provided below).

What I don't understand is how to convert from the frequency domain back to the time domain with respect to my sampling rate.

The data is sampled every 5 seconds (so 0.2Hz). Does the harmonic at 3Hz represent a repeating cycle every 15 seconds in the data (as in 1Hz is 5 seconds)? How do I correctly interpret the output?

Appreciate any help, example code below;

```
y <- 
c(203284,204481,205513,206543,207712,208971,209969,211135,212024,211770,211302,211104,209902,209463,
   209148,209006,208918,209329,209435,210143,210815,211601,212519,215102,215950,217140,218066,218363,
   218021,217549,217079,216630,216228,216080,215889,215130,214402,214051,213549,213135,212659,212257,
   211719,210872,210257,209659,208983,208531,207901,207727,207573,206873,206034,205410,204661,203876)

   ts <- c("2020-06-01 21:05:06 AEST","2020-06-01 21:05:11 AEST","2020-06-01 21:05:17 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:05:22 AEST","2020-06-01 21:05:28 AEST","2020-06-01 21:05:33 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:05:39 AEST","2020-06-01 21:05:44 AEST","2020-06-01 21:05:49 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:05:55 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:00 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:06 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:06:11 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:16 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:22 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:06:27 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:33 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:38 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:06:43 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:49 AEST","2020-06-01 21:06:54 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:07:00 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:05 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:10 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:07:16 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:21 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:27 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:07:32 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:38 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:43 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:07:48 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:54 AEST","2020-06-01 21:07:59 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:08:05 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:10 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:15 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:08:21 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:26 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:32 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:08:37 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:42 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:48 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:08:53 AEST","2020-06-01 21:08:59 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:04 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:09:10 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:15 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:20 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:09:26 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:31 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:37 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:09:42 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:48 AEST","2020-06-01 21:09:53 AEST",
   "2020-06-01 21:09:58 AEST","2020-06-01 21:10:04 AEST")

   ts <- as.POSIXct(ts)
   b <- data.frame(ts = ts, y = y)
   plot(b$ts, b$y, type = 'l')
   trend <- lm(y ~ ts, data = b) 

   detrended.trajectory <- trend$residuals  #de-trend the series
   plot(detrended.trajectory, type="l", main="detrended time series")

   library(GeneCycle)
   f.data <- GeneCycle::periodogram(detrended.trajectory)
   harmonics <- 1:20       
   plot(f.data$freq[harmonics]*length(detrended.trajectory), 
   f.data$spec[harmonics]/sum(f.data$spec), 
   xlab="Harmonics (Hz)", ylab="Amplitute Density", type="h")
```